# Fitting a pandas column containing a list in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame containing a column called 'X' containing a  list of 300 doubles and a column called 'label' when trying to run:

```
cls = SVC()
cls.fit(miniset.loc[:,'X'],miniset.loc[:,'label'])
```

I get the error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Head of my DataFrame

```
  label                                                  X
0      0  [-1.1990741, 0.98229957, -2.7413394, 0.5774205...
1      1  [0.10277234, 1.8292198, -1.8241594, 0.07206603...
2      0  [-0.26603428, 1.8654639, -2.2495375, -0.695124...
3      0  [-1.1662953, 3.0714324, -3.4975948, 0.01011618...
4      0  [-0.13769871, 1.9866339, -1.9885212, -0.830097...
```

Comment: Please show us the output of `miniset.head()` if the data is not sensitive.

Comment: @brentertainer it usually the other way around, where the `label` should be a series or a one dimensional array, and the `data` is a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @QuangHoang You're right, I mixed it up in my head.

Comment: @brentertainer added it to the original question

Comment: This is a standard pandas question, and has nothing to do with `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the 'X' column of your DataFrame. To get this to work with SVC (or basically any scikit-learn model), you need to split that column into several columns, one each for every element in your lists.

You can fix that by doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns).

The `pandas` package is not intended to store lists or other collections as values. It is meant to store **pan**el **da**ta, hence the name `pandas`.

Comment: Didn't want to corrupt my DataFrame with 300 columns so ended up running `cls.fit([x for x in dataset['X']],dataset.loc[:,'label'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cls.fit(np.array(miniset.loc[:,'X'].tolist()),miniset.loc[:,'label'])
```

where `tolist()` gives you a 2D array (which would be good enough).